# Show that the order of group $G$ is $1$ or a prime number

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

If I have a cyclic finite group $G$ that only has the subgroups $\{id\}$ and $G$.  How can I show that the order of $G$ is either $1$ or a prime number?

My first thought is to Lagrange's Theorem, stating that the order of all subgroups of a group must divide the order of the group.  Then since there are only two subgroups, and one only contains the identity then the number of elements in $G$ must be either $1$ or $p$.

From that, I'd reason that $p$ has to be a prime number since $G$ itself must be the other subgroup.

I don't feel this is the full proof though.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that every element has order $p$ for some fixed prime $p$ (why?). Next, note that if $g\in G\setminus\{1\}$ then for every $h\in G$ we have that $h\in\langle g\rangle$ (that is, the smallest sub group of $G$ containing $g$, which is cyclic, also contains $h$) (why?). The result follows (why?).

Answer (score 1):

For an element $a$ of order a number $n$, the element $a^k$ has order $\dfrac n{\gcd(n,k)}$. so if the only subgroups of $G$ are the trivial subgroups $\{1_G\}$ and $G$ it means that, for any $k$, $\gcd(n,k)$  is $1$ or $n$. This is possible only if the only divisors of $n$ are $1$ and $n$, i.e. if $n$ is prime.

Conversely, if $n$ is prime, $G$ is cyclic and its only subgroups, by *Lagrange's theorem*, are the trivial subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is incorrect at the point where you use Lagrange's theorem. True, the theorem claims that the order of a subgroup must divide the order of the group, but there is *no* claim to the converse, i.e. that, if *something* divides the order of the group, it must be an order of a subgroup. For example, a convenient [link from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Existence_of_subgroups_of_given_order) shows that there is a group of order $12$ with no subgroup of order $6$.

For a hopefully better proof, let $n=|G|$ and we need to prove that either $n=1$ or $n$ is prime. Suppose $n\gt 1$, so $G$ is nontrivial, and there is an element $a\in G, a\ne e$. Look at the (cyclic) group generated by $a$: $\langle a\rangle=\{a^k\mid k\in\mathbb N\}$. Because $a\ne e$, $\langle a\rangle$ is nontrivial, so it must then coincide with the whole $G$ (i.e. $G$ is cyclic). But then, if $n=|G|=|\langle a\rangle|$ was composite, say $n=mk$, then look at the subgroup generated by $a^k$: $|\langle a^k\rangle|=m$ so $G$ would have another subgroup of order $m, 1\lt m\lt n$ - contradiction!